# Help With jQuery DatePicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here is how I am setting DatePicker in js:

```
$('#created_at, #updated_at').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat',
                                         'dd.mm.yy 00:00:00');
```

What I am trying to achieve is for DatePicker to display date in a format like this:

```
12.02.2010 00:00:00
```

So basically just add "00:00:00" string after the date. But it's not working. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your why question, it's not in the [allowed list of formats](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate).  Since it's a date picker and not a time picker, I guess the issue doesn't come up enough to warrant adding the weight to the library to support it.

Comment: Thanks, I just add the time in PHP on server side.